# Problema con librería Masonry, no reconoce el height del div

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Buenas, hace poco escribí una pregunta para poder organizar divs con diferentes alturas en columnas. Resulto ser una pregunta ya respondida: **¿Como puedo crear columnas desorganizadas en bootstrap?**

El caso es que lo estoy probando y me funciona cuando lo trabajo aquí o fuera de la web. Cuando lo llevo a la página web hay algún error que hace que no funcione correctamente. Imagino que será algún problema con algún otro js.

A veces, no siempre se me montan unos div con otros, como si no reconociera el heigth del div y al estar en position:absolute, se solapan. Para verlo, en el caso de que se vea correctamente hay que **actualizar con ctrl+F5**.
Cuando redimensiono la ventana del explorador(crhome) se corrige el error y se reorganiza.

La página es:
https://www.joaquinlois.com/organos/restauracion-organos-historicos/

Cuando queda carga mal se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería de verse así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado trabajando el código aquí y claro, al no tener otros js se ve correctamente, he creado un pen en codepen y le he añadido librerías que tengo cargadas en la web, pero nada, no doy con el error. Dejo el código aquí, aunque este no tiene problemas.

```css
article.featured-organo{ margin-bottom:30px; display:block; text-align:center;}
article.featured-organo img{ width:90%; margin:0px auto;}
h1{text-align:center; margin-bottom:100px}
h4{font-size:14px; color:#999; font-style:italic; margin-bottom:10px;}
.content-features-organos{max-width:1200px; margin:0px auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/themes/joaquinlois/css/joaquinlois.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Masonry</h1>

<div class="grid content-features-organos">
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano<br> de Tordesillas<br>.<br>.<br>.</h3>
      <h4>Nombre <br>del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_sanpedro_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de <br>Salamanca</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/salamanca_detalles_01-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano del <br>Espinar</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_espinar_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de Zuera<br>.<br>.<br>.</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templos</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_zuera_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de <br>Cordoba</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/cordoba_general_II-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de <br>La Seca</h3>
      <h4>Nombre <br> del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/laseca_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano del Espinar</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templos</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_espinar_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de Fontiveros</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del templo</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_fontiveros_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <article class="grid-item featured-organo col-sm-3">
    <hgroup>
      <h3>Órgano de ...</h3>
      <h4>Nombre del <br> templos</h4>
    </hgroup>
    <img src="https://www.joaquinlois.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/organo_fontiveros_general-200x200.jpg" />
  </article>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
</script>
```

Adjunto también el código que tengo en la página, por si pudiera ser de ayuda, esta hecha en wordpress.

```html
<section id="lista-organos">

 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">   
   <?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=180"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
       <?php the_content(); ?>    
   <?php endwhile; ?>    
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6">
   <?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=1006"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
   
      <div class="grid content-features-organos">
     <?php if( have_rows('organ_repeater') ): ?>      
      <?php while( have_rows('organ_repeater') ): the_row(); 

       $image = get_sub_field('imagen_repeater');
       $size = 'thumbnail'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
      ?>
        <?php if(get_sub_field('new_restored_option', 'option') == 'restaurado') : ?>
         <article class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 featured-organo grid-item">
          <div class="featured-organo-content">
          <?php if(get_sub_field('title_repeater')): ?><h3><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link_repeater'); ?>"><span>órgano</span> <?php the_sub_field('title_repeater'); ?></a></h3><?php endif; ?>
          <?php if(get_sub_field('templo_repeater')): ?><h4> <?php the_sub_field('templo_repeater'); ?></h4><?php endif; ?>
          <?php if(get_sub_field('date_repeater')): ?><p class="fecha-organo"> (<?php the_sub_field('date_repeater'); ?>)</p><?php endif; ?>
           <a class="imagen" href="<?php the_sub_field('link_repeater'); ?>">
                           <img title="Restauración del órgano de <?php the_sub_field('title_repeater'); ?>"
                                    src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] ?>"
                                    alt="<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?> Restauración de Órganos Históricos
               <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?> Historic Pipe Organs Restauration
               <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de'): ?> Historic Pipe Organs Restauration
               <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'pt'): ?> Restauro de Orgãos Historicos<?php endif; ?>">
                       </a>
                   </div>
                   </article>
                 <?php endif; ?>              
      <?php endwhile; ?>      
     <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   
   <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

   <script>
    $('.grid').masonry({  // options
           itemSelector: '.grid-item'});
   </script>

 </div>
</section><!-- #post-## -->
```

He probado ha desactivar todos los plugins y tampoco

Bueno, creo que esto es todo, ando medio loko con esta chorrada. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por qué estás cargando tres versiones diferentes de jQuery? Con una debería ser suficiente

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema está en que estás llamando a `masonry()` antes de que se hayan cargado las imágenes, por tanto el alto del contenedor (`grid-item`) no es el definitivo cuando se reposicionan. Sí funciona cuando recargas la página porque las imágenes ya se han cargado antes y tardan menos, estando listas cuando se hace la llamada a `masonry()`.

Prueba a poner esto:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
});
```

Al estar dentro del `$(document).ready`, se ejecutará cuando haya terminado de cargarse la página (incluídas las imágenes) y debería funcionar de manera correcta.

Comment: Buenas Alvaro, gracias, he probado a poner el `$(document).ready` y parece que va mejor, pero aun sigue dando el error de vez en cuando. Si le fuerzas lo hace. ¿Podría ser que estuviera diciendo a las imágenes que carguen después? Creo que no lo he hecho específicamente. Pero si parece tener que ver con el tiempo de carga  de la página. Estoy intentando aligerar o reducir, pero dentro de mis limitaciones.

Comment: En cuanto a los  jQuery repetidos,  Cuales son? Creía que ahora solo tenia este:
`1<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Hay diferencias entre librerias jquery? de carga o de contenido? ademas de la actualidad de estas. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @beweb En el mismo código que compartes en la pregunta puedes ver como estás incluyendo la versión 3.1.1 y la 2.1.1 (están dos líneas aparte). Y, visitando la página que enlazas, ayer podía ver esas dos más la 1.12.4 (tres en total); hoy sólo veo la 3.1.1 y la 1.12.4, no sé si has cambiado algo o si ayer no lo vi bien

Comment: Buenas Avaro, si, vi tu comentario y quite un js, pero creo que el 1.12.4 me lo carga el plugin WPML, lo suyo seria quitar ese no? Y dejar el más actual. Aunque este va a buscarlo la carpeta wp-includes